What settings will brighten the view when using flash with a mirrorless Nikon Z camera?
I'm late to use mirrorless cameras, but recently tried using my father's old Nikon speedlight SB-24 and SB-80DX flashes with my Nikon Zf body.  Miraculously, the workflow of putting the camera in manual mode and using the flash TTL exposure almost works.
The resulting pictures are great, but composing them is difficult, since the camera viewfinder shows the unlit exposure. (I'm impressed that in an almost-blackened viewfinder, the Zf's feature detection and autofocus work reasonably well.)
Is there a mode or trick for the Zf (or mirrorless cameras generally) to display an overexposed image for composition and use the specified manual exposure in the resulting image?  Or is this just a coincidence that there's anything useful from pairing temporally-disparate technologies?

Just a sidenote:: with both those speedlights, you also have A (aka "non-TTL Auto") to automate flash power adjustment. It's a bit more cumbersome since you have to set iso/aperture on the flash. :D  But film-era flash TTL uses film reflectance while digital iTTL meters a preflash, the two TTLs don't always play nice together. And non-TTL works with the SB-80DX off-camera in optical slave mode.

Related: How can I preview exposure and autofocus with flash in a low light studio?

Menu d9; set it to "adjust for ease of view." On some Z's the "show effects of settings" option has a sub option of "only when flash is not used"... that also works well if enabled (not sure if Zf has it).

Nailed it!  Thank you.  The Zf has the "only when flash is not used", but I don't think the body detects that the ancient flash is in the hot shoe, so the switch isn't triggered.
